# An upper bound for the Chebyshev function?

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

The Chebyshev functions are defined as $\psi(x) = \sum_{p^m \leq x} \log n$ and $\theta(x) = \sum_{p\leq x} \log p$, where $p$ is a prime, $m\geq 1$ is an integer and $n=p^m$ in $\psi(x)$. It is known that there exist positive constants $c_{1}$ and $c_2$ such that
                                                                                 $c_{1}x < \psi(x) < c_{2} x$ and $ \frac{1}{2}c_{1}x < \theta(x) < c_{2} x$.     By these bounds we find that
                                                                                  $  \dfrac{ \psi(x) - x}{\psi(x) - \theta(x)} < \dfrac{(c_{2} -1)x}{(c_2 - c_1)x}  = \dfrac{c_{2} -1 }{c_2 - c_1} <\infty $.

Hence invoking the well known result  $\mid \psi(x) - \theta(x) \mid = O(x^{\frac{1}{2}}\log x)$, it then follows that $\mid \psi(x) - x \mid = O(x^{\frac{1}{2}}\log x)$ ?

EDIT: It is also known that $\theta (x)$ tends to $x$ as $x$ tends to $\infty$. Surely, an impication of this is $\dfrac{ \psi(x) - x}{\psi(x) - \theta(x)}  < \infty$ since $\psi(x) \neq \theta(x)$.

Comment: Note that $c_1 - c_2 < 0$. You don't have a lower bound $\psi(x) - \vartheta(x) > \gamma\cdot x$.

Comment: I think you're referring to the typo i just edited.

Comment: In that case, what's your argument for $$\frac{\psi(x) - x}{\psi(x) - \vartheta(x)} < \frac{(c_2-1)x}{(c_2-c_1)x}\,?$$

Comment: The $x's$ on the RHS cancel and we remain with a constant.

Comment: You do that after the step I'm asking about. One thing after the other.

Comment: Okay, what exactly are you asking about ?

Comment: Again, the result that $\theta(x)$ tends to $x$ as $x$ tends to infinity, surely implies that the concerned ratio is bounded above.

Comment: First, it's incorrect to say "$\theta(x)$ tends to $x$ as $x$ tends to infinity". What is true is that $\theta(x) \sim x$, or $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} \dfrac{\theta(x)}{x} = 1$. What I'm asking about is: How do you justify the inequality $$\frac{\psi(x) - x}{\psi(x) - \theta(x)} < \frac{(c_2 - 1)x}{(c_2 - c_1)x}\,?$$

Comment: In any case the notation you wrote is what i meant. As for the inequality: multiply the given bounds by -1 and then add, to arrive at the lower bound for the denominator $\psi(x) - \theta(x)$. The upper bound for the numerator is straightforward.

Comment: Problem is, you have $\psi(x) > c_1 x$ and $-\theta(x) > -c_2(x)$, so that only gives you the _negative_ lower bound $(c_1 - c_2)x$ for $\psi(x) - \theta(x)$.

Comment: Yes, infact what we need is the *modulus* of the ratio, so to be more neat i just *silently* wrote $\mid c_1 - c_2 \mid$ =$c_2 - c_1$. Check with the ratio inside a modulus, you will see that it is finite.

Comment: But that's wrong. Since we know $\theta(x) \leqslant \psi(x) \leqslant \theta(x) + C\sqrt{x}\log x$ for $x \geqslant 2$, it is impossible to have a bound $\lvert \psi(x) - \theta(x)\rvert \geqslant \gamma\cdot x$ with $\gamma > 0$.

Comment: Even so, the fact that $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\theta(x)}{x} =1$ definitely implies the required result that $\frac{\psi(x) -x}{\psi(x) - \theta(x)} < \infty$.

Comment: For a fixed $x \geqslant 4$, the quotient is of course finite since then $\psi(x) > \theta(x)$. But you can't deduce that the quotient is bounded above uniformly in $x$. If $\psi(x) - x > c\cdot x^{2/3}$ infinitely often for some $c > 0$, the quotient becomes arbitrarily large.

Comment: How can it not be bounded above uniformly yet both of $\psi(x)$ and $\theta(x)$ are bounded above uniformly ?

Comment: I don't understand that question. Neither $\psi(x)$ nor $\theta(x)$ is bounded above.

Comment: It is well known that $\psi(x), \theta(x) < kx$ for some positive constant $k$. In this question, $k=c_2$, therefore, i really don't understand your statement that ''neither of $\psi(x)$ nor $\theta(x)$ is bounded above".

Comment: Okay, so you mean $\psi(x)/x$ and $\theta(x)/x$ are uniformly bounded above. But that doesn't give you much, it is possible that $\psi(x) - \theta(x)$ is quite small. It might be _much_ smaller than $\psi(x) - x$. It's possible that that never happens, but we can't rule it out (yet), we don't know enough about the distribution of primes for that so far.

Comment: It may not give us ''much'', but it seems sufficient to establish that $\frac{\psi(x) -x}{\psi(x) - \theta(x)} < \infty$. Check by diving each term by $x$, and taking limits. Note that, since $\psi(x) \neq \theta(x)$, $\frac{\psi(x)}{x} \neq \frac{\theta(x)}{x}$ in the limit.

Comment: If by that you mean $\sup_x \frac{\psi(x) - x}{\psi(x) - \theta(x)} < \infty$, then: No, it is not sufficient to establish that. Not nearly. The $\psi(x) < kx$ and $\theta(x) < kx$ doesn't even rule out $\psi(x) \leqslant \theta(x)$ infinitely often. We know that that doesn't happen for $x \geqslant 4$, but we cannot deduce that just from the bounds.

Comment: Concerning the addition to your comment, note that $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\psi(x)}{x} = 1 = \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\theta(x)}{x}.$$ This is equivalent to the prime number theorem.

Comment: Yes that's the PNT, but that is not required in *this* context.

Comment: Dividing each term in the quotient by $x$, we have $\dfrac{\frac{\psi(x)}{x} -1}{\frac{\psi(x)}{x} - \frac{\theta(x)}{x}}$. Since we have $\frac{\psi(x)}{x} < k$ for some positive constant $k$ and the denominator is nonzero, it follows that the quotient is bounded above.

Comment: No. In $$\frac{\frac{\psi(x)}{x} - 1}{ \frac{\psi(x)}{x} - \frac{\theta(x)}{x}}$$ both, numerator and denominator tend to $0$ as $x\to \infty$. Thus we can't say that the fraction is bounded without knowing much more about the distribution of primes. And while it's straightforward to see that the denominator tends to $0$, the fact that the numerator tends to $0$ is equivalent to the PNT. So without the PNT, we couldn't rule out that the numerator is bounded below in absolute value by some $c > 0$, and then the (modulus of the) quotient would tend to $\infty$.

Comment: Please note that i *didn't take limits*, i just applied the result that $\frac{\psi(x)}{x} < k$ for some constant $k>0$ and the fact that $\psi(x) \neq \theta(x)$, which implies that the denominator is bounded and nonzero.

Comment: If you are looking at just one fixed $x$ ($\geqslant 4$), then the quotient is of course finite. But you cannot give a bound for it that is independent of $x$. Look at $a(x) = x+2$ and $b(x) = x + 1 + \frac{x}{1+x}\cdot \cos (\pi x)$. Then clearly $1 < \frac{a(x)}{x} < 3$ and $1 < \frac{b(x)}{x} < 3$ for $x > 1$, and $b(x) < a(x)$. But $$\frac{a(x) - x}{a(x) - b(x)} = \frac{2}{1 - \frac{x}{1+x}\cos (\pi x)}$$ becomes arbitrarily large, for $x = 2n,\, n \in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}$, it is $\dfrac{2}{1-\frac{2n}{2n+1}} = 4n+2$.

Comment: Thus you absolutely cannot deduce $$\frac{\psi(x) - x}{\psi(x) - \theta(x)} < \frac{c_2 - 1}{c_2 - c_1}$$ just from the bounds $c_1 x < \psi(x) < c_2 x$ and $\frac{1}{2} c_1 x < \theta(x) < c_2 x$.

Answer (score 2):

The inequality
\[\frac{\psi(x) - x}{\psi(x) - \vartheta(x)} < \frac{(c_2 - 1)x}{(c_2 - c_1)x}\]
is false, as Daniel Fischer mentions. The mistake is in the denominator; you know that $c_1 x < \psi(x) < c_2 x$ and $\frac{1}{2} c_1 x < \vartheta(x) < c_2 x$, but this does not imply that
\[\frac{1}{\psi(x) - \vartheta(x)} < \frac{1}{(c_2 - c_1)x},\]
or equivalently that
\[\psi(x) - \vartheta(x) > (c_2 - c_1)x.\]
In fact,
\[\psi(x) - \vartheta(x) = \sum_{\substack{p^m \leq x \\ m \geq 2}} \log p,\]
and from this it is easy to show that
\[\frac{1}{2} c_1 \sqrt{x} < \psi(x) - \vartheta(x) < c_3 \sqrt{x} \log x,\]
so the inequality is far from true.